# How to get selected value of cell on mouse click in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, controls

In `Asp.net C#`.I have a `gridview` control.

```
 col1

 - A
 - B
 - C
```

What I want that when I click on `A` then I should redirect to second page where 
i will perform a query and supply `'A'` as parameter in query and retrieve values
from database on the basis of `'A'`
For ex:

```
string query="select * from table1 where name='A'";
```

Q1.Is there any other way or control other than `gridview` which i can use in this situation.

Q2.If i use `Gridview` then how i can get value, save it in some field and then supplly it on next page and use it in query.

I have found things like `templatefields`,`linkbutton`,`hyperlink` but they do not seem to resolve my problem.

Comment: render a link like `secondpage.aspx?id=4` and let the user click on it.

Comment: kindly tell me how i can do this because there is no row or cell click event in gridview in asp.net

Comment: if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    e.Row.Attributes["onClick"] = "location.href='secondpage.aspx?id=" + DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "id") + "'";
}                      if i use this then the user is redirected to other page but how i can supply the 'A' in my query

Comment: I assume what Aristos means that you can provide the parameter needed in the link. Based on your answer-comment the first cell `e.Row.Cells[0].Text` has the value  you want to pass. Out of curiosity why do you want to use onclick for the cell using javascript instead of using a plain link inside the cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it useful to move this answer from comments, so this this can be helpful for others.

on `gridview_rowDataBound` event write this code

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.style.backgroundColor='#ceedfc'");
                e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.style.backgroundColor=''");
                e.Row.Attributes.Add("style", "cursor:pointer;");
                e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "location='WebForm3.aspx?id=" + e.Row.Cells[0].Text + "'");
            }
```

then on next page get value of id by

```
Id = Request.QueryString["ID"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

The very simplistic way is make A a HyperLinkField which navigates to the second page and passes the querystring.  You can do what you say with javascript by attaching to the table cell click event, and then on click, grab the cell's contents via cell.innerHTML and pass that to the second page, passing the value via the querystring.  The very simplistic way is use a link.  Add to your grid:

```
<asp:HyperLinkColumn DataNavigateUrlFormatString="SecondPage?value={0}"
   DataNavigateUrlFields="ColumnNameOfWhateverAIs" 
   DataTextField="ColumnNameOfWhateverAIs" />
```

Comment: Thanks to all contributors i have found my answer but since i have no permission to post my anser so thats why i am posting my answer in comments so that other can benefit from it.

Comment: Thanks to all and i finally got my answer
on gridview_rowDataBound event write this code
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.style.backgroundColor='#ceedfc'");
                    e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.style.backgroundColor=''");
                    e.Row.Attributes.Add("style", "cursor:pointer;");
                    e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "location='WebForm3.aspx?id=" + e.Row.Cells[0].Text + "'");
                }

then on next page got value of id by 
    Id = Request.QueryString["ID"].ToString();